# How to fix this Java code in order for it to work for all the grades not only A?

Tags: java

What should I change?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Grades
    {
        public String scoreToGrade( int score )
        {
            String grade = "";
            if( score <= 100 )
            {
                if( score >= 90 )
                    grade = "A";

            }
            else if( score <= 89 )
            {
                if( score >= 80 )
                    grade = "B";
                    return grade;

            }
            else if( score <= 79 )
            {
                if( score >= 70 )
                    grade = "C";
             return grade;
            }
            else if( score <= 69 )
            {
                if( score >= 60 )
                    grade = "D";
             return grade;
            }
            else if( score <= 59 )
            {
                if( score >= 50 )
                    grade = "E";
               return grade;
            }
             else if( score <= 49 )
            {
                if( score >= 0 )
                    grade = "F";
          return grade;
            }
            else
            {
                grade = "Error: score " + score;
            }
            return grade;
        }

        public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Score: " );
            int score = Integer.parseInt( input );
            Grades t = new Grades();
            String grade = t.scoreToGrade( score );
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,
                    "For " + score + " points, your grade is:  " + grade );
        }
    }
```

I think the problem is with return grade; I tried to add a return grade; statement below every grade but it wouldn't work either.
I think the problem is with return grade; I tried to add a return grade; statement below every grade but it wouldn't work either.

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs (external link)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Just imagine `score` to be 61 and "execute your code by hand".

Comment: You have to start verifying conditions from smallest value, not from greatest.
In your code all scores fall to first "if".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply need curly brackets around ALL of your if statements.  Eg

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Grades
{
public String scoreToGrade( int score )
{
    String grade = "";
    if( score <= 100 )
    {
        if( score >= 90 ){
            grade = "A";
            return grade;
        }
    }
    else if( score <= 89 )
    {
        if( score >= 80 ) {
            grade = "B";
            return grade;
        }

    }
    else if( score <= 79 )
    {
        if( score >= 70 ) {
            grade = "C";
            return grade;
        }
    }
    else if( score <= 69 )
    {
        if( score >= 60 ) {
            grade = "D";
            return grade;
        }
    }
    else if( score <= 59 )
    {
        if( score >= 50 ) {
            grade = "E";
            return grade;
        }
    }
    else if( score <= 49 )
    {
        if( score >= 0 ) {
            grade = "F";
            return grade;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        grade = "Error: score " + score;
    }
    return grade;
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Score: " );
    int score = Integer.parseInt( input );
    Grades t = new Grades();
    String grade = t.scoreToGrade( score );
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,
        "For " + score + " points, your grade is:  " + grade );
}
}
```

Might be missing something else though.

Comment: @JrSomeone This can't be the right answer since it wouldn't return the right grade at all!

Comment: And why would that be the case?

Comment: if the score is 80, then it would go inside the first if ` if( score <= 100 )` and not inside the second `else if ` where you set the grade to `B`. And please don't downvote my answer just because I pointed out that this answer needs to be corrected.

Comment: I have no intention of doing so. But you're right, I totally missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Grades
{
    public String scoreToGrade( int score )
    {
        String grade;
        if( score < 50 ) return "F";
        else if( score >= 50 && score < 60) return "E";
        else if( score >= 60 && score < 70) return "D";
        else if( score >= 70 && score < 80) return "C";
        else if( score >= 80 && score < 90) return "B";
        else if( score > 90) return "A";
        else
        {
            grade = "Error: score " + score;
        }
        return grade;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Score: " );
        int score = Integer.parseInt( input );
        Grades t = new Grades();
        String grade = t.scoreToGrade( score );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,
                "For " + score + " points, your grade is:  " + grade );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Turing85 has given you a good advice. I would suggest you to follow that to understand what has gone wrong in your code.

But to help you in this particular situation, the issue why you're code is not working for any other grades is the way you have structured your `if` conditions.

Consider the below snippet from your code:

```
        if( score <= 100 )
        {
            if( score >= 90 )
                grade = "A";

        }
        else if( score <= 89 )
        {
            if( score >= 80 )
                grade = "B";
                return grade;

        }
```

If `score` is `>=90`, `grade` is being set as `A`. But if `score` is not `>=90` but `<=100`, then it wouldn't go to the `else if` block where you set it to `B`, since it would directly go out the `else if` ladder from the `if( score <= 100 )` condition.

So you should refactor the method as below:

```
public static String scoreToGrade( int score )
        {
            String grade = "";
            if( score <= 100 && score >= 90 )
            {
                    grade = "A";
            }
            else if( score <= 89 && score >= 80)
            {
                    grade = "B";
            }
            else if( score <= 79 && score >= 70)
            {
                    grade = "C";
            }
            else if( score <= 69 && score >= 60)
            {
                    grade = "D";
            }
            else if( score <= 59 && score >= 50)
            {
                    grade = "E";
            }
            else if( score <= 49 && score >= 0)
            {
                    grade = "F";
            }
            else
            {
                grade = "Error: score " + score;
            }
            return grade;
        }
```